# How to retrieve the data from a Bundle constructed by another bundle?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

As show below in the code, I am creating a new bundle `meetingPointFixBundle` constructed with another bundle which will be returned by `getAddNewLocationBundle`

And somewhere in my code I want to

(1) unpack the bundle `meetingPointFixBundle` and retrieve all the values I added to it explicitly and

(2)get the values contained in the bundle `getAddNewLocationBundle`.

Actually, I know how to do the first part of the question, it will be accomplished using `meetingPointFixBundle = getIntent().getExtras()`. But I do not know how too retrieve the values contained in the bundle `getAddNewLocationBundle` through `meetingPointFixBundle`?

Any suggestion?

***Update/further explanation***

The `starterActivityBundle` has three keys [LOC_NAME_KEY, IMG_TITLE_KEY, IMG_PATH_KEY].
And, In the Current activity, I am Creating its own bundle`getMeetingPointFixBundle` which is initially constructed with the `starterActivityBundle`. And later in the code, I will add extra two keys-[LOC_LAT_KEY, LOC_LNG_KEY]- to the current activity bundle `getMeetingPointFixBundle`. So, the final format of `getMeetingPointFixBundle` will look like this `getMeetingPointFixBundle[starterActivityBundle, LOC_LAT_KEY, LOC_LNG_KEY]`.

And Later, I will start a new activity "InfoActivity" by an `intent` populated with `getMeetingPointFixBundle`. And from inside "InfoActivity" I want to unpack `getMeetingPointFixBundle` and retrieve `[starterActivityBundle (LOC_NAME_KEY, IMG_TITLE_KEY, IMG_PATH_KEY), getMeetingPointFixBundle (LOC_LAT_KEY, LOC_LNG_KEY) ]`

StarterActivitybundle:

```
private Bundle getTheStarterActivityBundle() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    this.addNewLocationBundle = new Bundle();
    this.addNewLocationBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    return this.addNewLocationBundle;
}
```

getMeetingPointFixBundle:

```
protected Bundle getMeetingPointFixBundle() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.i(CURRENT_ACTIVITY, "@getMeetingPointFixBundle(): A New Bundle For MeetingPointFix Activity Constructed With "
            + "A Copy Of The Bundle Of AddNewLocation Activity, Is created");
    meetingPointFixBundle = new Bundle(getAddNewLocationBundle());
    return meetingPointFixBundle;
}
```

Comment: What kind of data are you storing inside your bundles? Because that's the first you need to know in order to retrieve their values. For instance, if a bundle stores Strings, you can retrieve this values like this: meetingPointFixedBundle.getString("keyName")

Comment: would you please see the upadate

Comment: the data type is either strings or double. and i know how to retrieve data added to  a bundle. but i do not know how to retrieve from the current bundle i have, data which is contained in another bundle. I hope it is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have trouble understanding your question, but I’ll take a shot at what I think you’re trying to achieve.

As far as I can tell, you’re trying to get the extras from a specific `Bundle`. The problem is, you’re “merging” them together. The following may help:

```
protected Bundle getMeetingPointFixBundle() {
  final Bundle newLocationBundle = getAddNewLocationBundle();
  final Bundle meetingPointFixBundle = new Bundle();
  meetingPointFixBundle.putBundle("locationBundle", newLocationBundle); 
  return meetingPointFixBundle;
}
```

Then, to get (1), you can use your approach, but ignore the "locationBundle" extra.

For (2), you can call `getIntent().getBundleExtra("locationBundle")` to access the `newLocationBundle` extras.

*UPDATE*

> And from inside "InfoActivity" I want to unpack
>   getMeetingPointFixBundle and retrieve [starterActivityBundle
>   (LOC_NAME_KEY, IMG_TITLE_KEY, IMG_PATH_KEY), getMeetingPointFixBundle
>   (LOC_LAT_KEY, LOC_LNG_KEY) ]

Again, I’m a bit confused by the explanation and the syntax you’re using. I’ll assume `X = [Y(Z)]` means Bundle X contains extra value Z from a Bundle Y.

> So, the final format of getMeetingPointFixBundle will look like this
>   getMeetingPointFixBundle[starterActivityBundle, LOC_LAT_KEY,
>   LOC_LNG_KEY]. And Later, I will start a new activity "InfoActivity" by
>   an intent populated with getMeetingPointFixBundle

By using `getMeetingPointFixBundle()` as you define it in your question, and keeping in mind the final format of `getMeetingPointFixBundle`, the Bundle in your `InfoActivity` should contain the following extras: `[LOC_NAME_KEY, IMG_TITLE_KEY, IMG_PATH_KEY, LOC_LAT_KEY, LOC_LNG_KEY]`. Extracting the data is then as simple as calling the appropriate Bundle getter method.

If this is not what you're looking for, then I apologise, but I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: yes, i created a sample project to know how can i solve it. but I solved the same way you suggested in your update. so the conclusion is, if a new bundle is created and constructed by another bundle, all the data/values available in the bundle that constructed the new one, could be easily retrieved by referring to its KEY through the newly constructed bundle.

Comment: I’m glad you figured it out. In the future, make sure to check the official [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#Bundle(android.os.Bundle)) too. :)